# Getting wrong parameter count for Google NASNet-A neural net

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I’m trying to understand the NASNet-A architecture in detail, but can’t match the parameter counts in the paper.

For example, the paper says CIFAR-10 NASNet-A “6 @ 768” model has 3.3M params, but by my calculations a single “sep 5x5” primitive in the final cell should alone have 2.9M params… which can’t be right!

Here’s how I derive this count…

The “6 @ 768” notation means the “number of filters in the penultimate layer of the network” is 768, which I assume means the number of filters in each of the primitive operations in the cell is 768, and therefore the output depth of the concat operation (with 5 block inputs) is 5 * 768. Since shape is only changed by reduction cells, the input to the final cell (concat output from prior normal cell) will also be of depth 5 * 768.

So for a 5x5 separable convolution with 5 * 768 input channels and 768 output channels, the number of parameters is:

5x5x1 * (5 * 768)  = 96,00 params for the 5x5 depthwise filters, plus

1x1x(5 * 768) x 768 = 2,949,128 params for the 1x1 pointwise filters

Where am I going wrong?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of output channels from each operation of cell's block is according to the defined `num_conv_filters`. In example for CIFAR NASNet-A is 32, and it doubles after each `Reduction Cell`.

Although they mention they have B=5 blocks and no residual connection it seems they have 6 concatenated chunks of filters, the last seem to come from the previous layer.
See: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/d07447a3e34bc66acd9ba7267437ebe9d15b45c0/research/slim/nets/nasnet/nasnet_utils.py#L309

This is why for example you have 192 feature depth in the first cell:
6*32=192.
You can take a look on the expected depths here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/d07447a3e34bc66acd9ba7267437ebe9d15b45c0/research/slim/nets/nasnet/nasnet_test.py#L127

So for example, for the last `5x5 separable convolution` you can get:
5x5*768 + 768*128 = 117504 parametes

For more info about the separable convolution:
http://forums.fast.ai/t/how-depthwise-separable-convolutions-work/4249